# .Net Winforms/WPF Editor that generate HTML

Tags: html, wpf, winforms, text, editor

Looking and .Net Rich Editor that generates HTML, it is important to be capable of handling Tables, merging Cells among other table stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CuteEditor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) are probably your best bets.

Disclaimer: WYSIWYG editors bring their own brand of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

you can use webbrowser control
**EDIT**
This will convert your webbrowser control to HTML Editor

```
...


webBrowser.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigated);

webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");

void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     var doc = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

     if (doc != null)
           doc.designMode = "On";
}
```

and here is how you can call commands on browser

```
public IHTMLDocument2 Document
{
    get
    {
        return webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    }
 }
 public void SelectAll()
 {
      Document.execCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use webbrowser control to edit html. It can be used in WPF or Winform.
There some ready components based on webbrowser control such as http://smithhtmleditor.codeplex.com/
but unfortunately because webbrowser control is based on com, it is likely that it does not work in all computers and you might get errors in some(because of version of com and ...) as we had.

DevExpress has a richeditor that might help( http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Previews-from-DevExpress-Silverlight-Rich-Edit-Control.aspx ) you can load and save html document in it.